# Javascript 2 similar codes are not working together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I use this very typical js code to show a div when selected certain value.

http://jsfiddle.net/FvMYz/

```
 $(function() {
    $('#craft').change(function(){
        $('.colors').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    });
});
```

But I want to make this js code work for select 2 options and 2 divs, so I add another script with different names like in below but it fails. When other select option chosen first div things show up.

```
$(function() {
    $('#craft2').change(function(){
        $('.colors2').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    });
});
```

My full code here.

1.options and divs

```
{!! Form::select('id', $upgradeable_items, null, array('id' => 'craft')) !!}

@foreach($reals as $real)
    <div id="{{$real->id}}" class="colors" style=";width: 250px; display:none">
        +{{$real->type}}  <img style="margin-left: 20px" class="marketpics" src="{{$real->picturePath}}">
    </div>
@endforeach
```

2.options and div

```
{!! Form::select('id', $charms, null, array('id' => 'craft2')) !!}

@foreach($chars as $char)
    <div id="{{$char->item_id}}" class="colors2" style="float: right;width: 250px; display:none">
        <img style="margin-left: 20px" class="marketpics" src="{{$char->picturePath}}">
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Any ideas how I can solve this overlaping problem... When I choose options in 2.option dropdown list, they appear in 1.div and overlap and overlap again. But when I choose option from 1.option dropdown list, there is no problem. Its properly showing up in 1.div.

Comment: do the two sets of select options have the same values and thus the divs have the same sets of IDs? IDs are meant to be unique can only be used once on a given page and a document query will only find the first instance of a given ID if it appears multiple times.  So you need to make your ID's unique.

Comment: yeah, I get that this is the problem but they also have different classes.. So If they have same ID's it will always overlap you mean?

Comment: Yes. ID's need to be unique. The ID / Class combination doesn't matter. Document queries assume unique ID's.

Comment: any ideas how i can add unique ID to my second divs? I try like id="asdasd{{$char->item_id}}" but its not working. Because I need to show different divs depending on a option value(which I will have many).

Comment: did you also update the associated jquery selector?

Comment: what do you mean by update bryan?

Comment: see my answer. If you change the ID's you also need to reflect that in your selector function.

Comment: I tried but Its not working still.. I even try different versions of your answer but.. not working.

Comment: Must be missing something or it's something in the HTML templating language you're using, I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: So this is laravel I use, but like why its still not working.. I changed as you suggested but not working.

Comment: not sure, as you can see in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FvMYz/4508/  it works fine.  You must be missing a piece in your implementation.

Comment: yeah you are right, i will try again from the beginning..

Comment: YEAH! Finally it worked. I fixed some small mistakes. like a selected value. Thank you Bryan. maybe add this answer to your answer. I approve yours now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enforce unique ID's in your HTML if you're using document queries as ID doc queries will only ever return the first instance of an ID.  Just make sure to add something unique to each selector and the corresponding query like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#craft2').change(function(){
        $('.colors2').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val() + '2').show();
    });
});

{!! Form::select('id', $charms, null, array('id' => 'craft2')) !!}

 @foreach($chars as $char)
<div id="{{$char->item_id}}2" class="colors2" style="float: right;width: 250px; display:none"><img style="margin-left: 20px" class="marketpics" src="{{$char->picturePath}}"></div> @endforeach
```

working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FvMYz/4508/

Comment: thank you bryan :) you can change -2 to 2 in js and in div also :)

Comment: sure but it shouldn't mater, dashes are valid ID characters (http://jsfiddle.net/FvMYz/4509/), unless there is something bout laravel that doesn't like them

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the divs different IDs, as you may only have one instance of an ID. If theres more than one instance of an ID, and you make a query for that specific ID; then it will always return the first instance of the ID.

So on the first it should be: ID = "red", and on the seconds it should be ID = "red2".

Furthermore you have to make your second js code search for the belonging IDs, as shown below.

```
$(function() {
     $('#craft2').change(function(){
           $('.colors2').hide();
           $('#' + $(this).val() + '2').show();
     });
});
```

UPDATE:
You should add "2" to the end of each ID, like this:

```
<div id="{{$char->item_id}}2" class="colors2" style="float: right;width: 250px; display:none">
    <img style="margin-left: 20px" class="marketpics" src="{{$char->picturePath}}">
</div>
```

Comment: How i should add in div? <div id="{{$char->item_id}}2" or <div id="{{$char->item_id+2}}" or <div id="{{($char->item_id)+2}}"

Comment: However, I would suggest, that you take a look at Bhuwan Bhatts answer. As it is better code.

Comment: thank you roli! your answer is true as well as bryan's :) thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use `classes` instead of `IDs` for the colors because colors can be same.

And wrap your one select box and their elements into one `div` with some class so that you can use this class to show hide the elements on change.

You also no need to write javascript code for all select box. If you use class and below markup structure it will be easy for you.

***Stack Snippet***

```js
$(function() {
  $('.craft').change(function() {
    $(this).closest('.wrap').find('.colors').hide();
    $(this).closest('.wrap').find('.' + $(this).val()).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <select class="craft" id="colorselector">
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  </select>
  <div class="red colors" style="display:none"> red... </div>
  <div class="yellow colors" style="display:none"> yellow.. </div>
  <div class="blue colors" style="display:none"> blue.. </div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <select class="craft" id="colorselector">
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  </select>
  <div class="red colors" style="display:none"> red... </div>
  <div class="yellow colors" style="display:none"> yellow.. </div>
  <div class="blue colors" style="display:none"> blue.. </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Berke Sorry to say...:(....I don't know much about laravel....but you can find the ways to implement this by doing some research